# How to select between an actual routerLink and an internal anchor with Angular 8?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, anchor, routerlink

I have an array of items, which looks like this:

```
nav: any = [
  {
    name: 'Homepage',
    url: 'homepage'
    internal: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Section 1',
    hash: 'section-1'
    internal: true
  },
];
```

Now I need to ouput a list of `a`-elements. These should either contain a `routerLink` if `internal` is *false* – or they should become an internal anchor. I've tried:

```
<a class="link"
   *ngFor="for item of nav"
   [href]="item.internal ? '#' + item.hash : null"
   [routerLink]="item.internal ? null : item.url">
  {{ item.title }}
</a>
```

This renders `homepage` correctly, but `Section 1` comes out wrongly:

```
<a class="link" href="/homepage">Homepage</a>
<a class="link" href="/">Section 1</a>
```

This is what I actually want:

```
<a class="link" href="/homepage">Homepage</a>
<a class="link" href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
```

How to achieve this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<a class="link" *ngFor="for item of nav" [routerLink]="item.internal ? '#' + item.hash : item.url">
 {{ item.title }}
</a>
```

The routerLink replaces by href after render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried that already. It results in `/%23section-1`, which doesn't seem valid. It also throws "*Cannot match any routes*".

Answer (score 0):

why not conditionally, use one or the other?

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="internal">
     show appropriate link
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container *ngIf="!internal">
     show appropriate link
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, I could probably solve it like this. I was hoping for a more elegant and simpler solution. :)